# variables to the power of a fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I have this question for advanced math, I can't seem to get my head around.

$$\frac{x^{5/2}}{(x^{1/3})^4}$$

Answer (score 1):

Use this identity:

$$\frac{a^m}{a^n}=a^{m-n}$$

Answer (score 0):

You should use the identity Rory suggested. Using that, you get the following:
$$
\frac{x^{5/2}}{(x^{1/3})^4} = x^{5/2-4/3}=x^{15/6-8/6}=x^{7/6} 
$$

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the advice, but the correct answer is x^7/6, how would we get to that? the original question is x^5/2 % (x^1/3)^4 if that helps. so i simplified by changing the last sum to x^4/3

Comment: @Josh Then the meaning of your original question was changed. Check this out: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E%282%2F5%29%2Fx%5E%284%2F3%29

Comment: @Josh by the % sign do you mean division or multiplication?

Comment: division, sorry i'm not use to how to write correctly on this yet.

Comment: @Josh Does x^5/2 mean $x^{5/2}=x^{\frac{5}{2}}$?

Comment: yes sorry it does, so x^5/2 % (x^1/3)^4

Comment: Ah yes. Apparently it was modified to be $x^{2/5}$ instead of the $x^{5/2}$ as you just wrote. Check my modified answer in a moment.